# Error copying from resources

Tags: vb.net, resources, copy

While copying from resources to a folder under appdata folder: i get an error, but I'm not finding any mistake in code..

```
Private Sub Help_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    File.WriteAllBytes(MainPath & "\Help.rtf", My.Resources.HelpRTF)

    Dim HelpRTF = (MainPath & "\Help.rtf")
    Helpbox.LoadFile(HelpRTF)
End Sub
```

`HelpRTF` is a .rtf file, `MainPath` is a directory under `%appdata%` folder

Error: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Byte()'.

Error at: `My.Resources.HelpRTF`

Comment: What part of the error is confusing?  `WriteAllBytes` expects the second param to be an array of bytes (hence the clever name). `HelpRTF` is apparently a string.  Depending on how you constructed `MainPath`, it may fail trying to write there.

Comment: As @Plutonix says, `WriteAllBytes` is for writing bytes.  If you want to write text then I'd suggest `WriteAllText` instead.

Comment: @Plutonix i'm going to try it

Comment: @Plutonix this worked, but now i get `Resources is not a member of MyApp.My` error

Comment: @Plutonix EDIT: problem fixed. nothing wrong now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get that error is because the second parameter of the `File.WriteAllBytes()` method takes a `Byte()`, not a `String`. If you want to write text (`String`) to a file, you can use the `File.WriteAllText()` method.

Since RTF's can contain images, text, etc. treating it as text can corrupt it and needless to say, encoding issues might occur. So, instead of using the `File.WriteAllText()` method, change the `FileType` of the `HelpRTF` resource to `Binary` instead of `Text` like this:

[image: Screenshot]

After that, you can use your code as it was:

```
Private Sub Help_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    File.WriteAllBytes(MainPath & "\Help.rtf", My.Resources.HelpRTF)
    Dim HelpRTF = (SWinPath & "\Help.rtf")
    Helpbox.LoadFile(HelpRTF)
End Sub
```

References:

- [`File.WriteAllText` - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`File.WriteAllBytes` - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: this worked, and my code worked too, there was a problem with `Resources.resx` properties: i only changed a letter in default `Custom Tool Namespace` value then changed it back to default (default: `My.Resources`).. either visual studio got crazy or computer is crazy. fixed problem by changing nothing